# How do you handle optional schema/attribute?

Tags: normalizr

I would like to know how do to handle an optional attribute in a schema.

For instance, I've got like:

```
const billSchema = new schema.Entity('bills')

billSchema.define({
  _embedded: {
    currentStep: stepSchema,
    latestText: textSchema,
    steps: [stepSchema],
  }
})
```

Sometimes on some requests, "steps" exists but on others, it doesn't. And I 'd like not to create a schema for each type of API request.

Any idea?